# Java networking | Streams are working only 1 time

Tags: java, networking, client

Im working on a little chat program and now i have a huge problem and i can not solve it.
I dont know where the mistake could be, for me the code is right. So i really really need help. I have 2 threads in my server, 1 thread for accepting clients and the other for the streams. And the thread for the streams is not working right. It sends only 1 time a message back to the client and multiple clients are also not working. And there is another strange problem. I can only send 1 message back, if i put the JOptionPane-message called "Sockets empty" in the else statement, without it doesnt work.
Here is the stream thread code:

```
private static Runnable streamThread = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(!(socketList.isEmpty()))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < socketList.size(); i++)
                {           
                    try 
                    {
                        String key = socketList.get(i);

                        if(socketHashMap.containsKey(key))
                        {
                            Socket connection = socketHashMap.get(key);

                            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

                            String response = (String) ois.readObject();

                            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                            oos.writeObject(key + ": " + response);
                            oos.flush();
                        }                       
                        if(connection.isClosed())
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Client closed connection", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: " + e.getMessage(), "ALARM", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        try {
                            connection.close();
                            connection.shutdownInput();
                            connection.shutdownOutput();

                            listClientsModel.remove(i);
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                        }

                    }                   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SOCKETS LEER", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        } 
    }
};
```

And if you want to see the complete servercode :
http://pastebin.com/sxGGRnJv

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [getOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream%28%29) says:

> Closing the returned OutputStream **will close the associated socket**.

And that is the problem. You create an ObjectOutputStream, but don't keep a reference to that object around. As this object gets garbage collected, it **will call close() which will close the socket's output stream**.

Same problem with the InputStream.

You could, for example, create a class that contains your socket and input and output stream and store that in your map instead of just the socket. That way you can re-use the streams.

Comment: I dont know if i really understand the part with the reference, what do you mean with the object around? Does it mean that i can´t create a second stream from the same socket? So i have to create a reference to the stream and re-use them. I created a new class called connectionClass and created a new instance whenever a client joints. The instance gets the socket and all streams + username. But its not working right, i get everytime a NullPointerException when i try to do something with the connectionClass, that is a sign that nothing is in there.

Comment: Here is the new Connection.class where i store the streams+socket+username : http://pastebin.com/b2Sj3Ytm. Here i create a instance of Connection: http://pastebin.com/udiaVHnT and here i try to do something with it: http://pastebin.com/PAni6KWk

Comment: Do you put the new Connection objects into the list? Also, there is no more output.flush() in your code.
Otherwise it looks okay from what I can see.